# x509 restrict the intermediate CA to sign only end user certificates

Tags: openssl, ssl-certificate, x509

I am trying to restrict the intermediate CA to sign only end user certificates. However, I am not able to do so.

Man page of **x509v3_config** says

> basicConstraints=critical,CA:TRUE, pathlen:0
>
> A CA certificate must include the basicConstraints value with the CA
> field set to TRUE . An end user certificate must either set CA to
> FALSE or exclude the extension entirely. Some software may require the
> inclusion of basicConstraints with CA set to FALSE for end entity
> certificates.
>
> *The pathlen parameter indicates the maximum number of CAs that can appear below this one in a chain. So if you have a CA with a pathlen
> of zero it can only be used to sign end user certificates and not
> further CAs*

**Step 1:** Create a self signed root CA - rootCA.crt

```
openssl genrsa -out rootCA.key 4096

openssl req -x509 -new -nodes -key rootCA.key -sha256 -out rootCA.crt
```

**Step 2:** Create a Certificate signing request using below configuration file.

```
openssl req -new -config extension.conf -out intermediate.csr
```

```
[ req ]
 default_bits       = 4096
 default_md         = sha256
 prompt             = no
 encrypt_key        = no
 default_keyfile    = privkey.key
 distinguished_name = req_distinguished_name
 req_extensions     = v3_req
 
 [ req_distinguished_name ]
 countryName            = DE
 stateOrProvinceName    = Bayern
 localityName           = Munich
 0.organizationName     = Test AG
 organizationalUnitName = Services
 emailAddress           = services.dept@test.de
 
 [ v3_req ]
 basicConstraints       = critical,CA:true, pathlen:0
 keyUsage               = keyCertSign
```

The CSR is generated now

**Step 3:** Now sign the CSR with self-signed root CA with support from extension file

```
openssl x509 -req -in intermediate.csr -CA rootCA.crt -CAkey rootCA.key -CAcreateserial -extensions v3_req -extfile file.txt -out intermediate.crt -sha256
```

file.txt

```
[ v3_req ]
 subjectKeyIdentifier   = hash
 authorityKeyIdentifier = keyid:always
```

Now intermediate certificate is generated.

**Step 4:** Create one more intermediate certificate and lets call it **TEST** certificate - using sightly modified configuration file as below:

```
[ req ]
 default_bits       = 4096
 default_md         = sha256
 prompt             = no
 encrypt_key        = no
 default_keyfile    = privkey.key
 distinguished_name = req_distinguished_name
 req_extensions     = v3_req
 
 [ req_distinguished_name ]
 countryName            = DE
 stateOrProvinceName    = Berlin
 localityName           = Berlin
 0.organizationName     = Dummy AG
 organizationalUnitName = Product
 emailAddress           = product.dept@dummy.de
 
 [ v3_req ]
 basicConstraints       = critical,CA:true
 keyUsage               = keyCertSign
```

Generate the CSR

```
openssl req -new -config test.conf -out TEST.csr
```

Sign the CSR with **intermediate.crt** which should not be possible.

```
openssl x509 -req -in TEST.csr -CA intermediate.crt -CAkey privkey.key -CAcreateserial -out TEST.crt -sha256
```

As per the **man** page of **x509v3_config**, signing of the TEST.csr should fail as it is not the end user certificate.

The pathlen is 0 in my intermediate certificate. So I shouldn't be able to sign the TEST.csr. What am I doing wrong here? Can some one please kindly explain?

Comment: run validation for your last certificate. Is it considered valid or not? If not, then everything is ok.

Comment: This was cross-posted to [security.se] and is likely a better fit there. I propose to close it here.

Comment: As I am not sure which is the right forum, I posted on both sites. I will close this one. Thank you